# Fastest way to convert a set of 3D points into image of heights in python

Tags: python, performance, 3d, heightmap

I am trying to convert a set of 3D points into a heightmap (a 2d image that shows the largest displacements of the points from the floor)

The only way I can come up with is writing a for look that iterates through all points and update the heightmap, this method, is quite slow.

```
import numpy as np

heightmap_resolution = 0.02

# generate some random 3D points
points =  np.array([[x,y,z] for x in np.random.uniform(0,2,100) for y in np.random.uniform(0,2,100) for z in np.random.uniform(0,2,100)])


heightmap = np.zeros((int(np.max(points[:,1])/heightmap_resolution) + 1,
                  int(np.max(points[:,0])/heightmap_resolution) + 1))

for point in points:
    y = int(point[1]/heightmap_resolution)
    x = int(point[0]/heightmap_resolution)
    if point[2] > heightmap[y][x]:
        heightmap[y][x] = point[2]
```

I wonder if there is a better way of doing this. Any improvement is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The intuition:
If you find yourself using a for loop with numpy, you probably need to check again if numpy has an operation for it.  I saw you wanted to compare items to get max and I wasn't sure if the structure was imporant so I changed it.

2nd point is heightmap is pre-allocating a lot of memory you aren't going to use.  Try using a dictionary with a tuple (x,y) as the key or this (a dataframe)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

heightmap_resolution = 0.02

# generate some random 3D points
points =  np.array([[x,y,z] for x in np.random.uniform(0,2,100) for y in np.random.uniform(0,2,100) for z in np.random.uniform(0,2,100)])
points_df = pd.DataFrame(points, columns = ['x','y','z'])
#didn't know if you wanted to keep the x and y columns so I made new ones.
points_df['x_normalized'] = (points_df['x']/heightmap_resolution).astype(int)
points_df['y_normalized'] = (points_df['y']/heightmap_resolution).astype(int)
points_df.groupby(['x_normalized','y_normalized'])['z'].max()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I can see this saves a lot of time if I want to inquire a displacement for each pixel. However, I will be doing additions as well as rotations with the heightmap images so I still prefer to have numpy array structure. Is there a neat way to convert this into heightmaps instead of inquire each pixel by key?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem. Initially I used a similar approach than the one shown in the question, but it was way too slow. Here is how I made it roughly 30 times more efficient.

My `data` were `N` particles placed on a grid, with 3 columns for their coordinates x,y,z, with `data.shape` `(N,3)`. I wanted to convert it to a heightmap of shape `(gridsize_x, gridsize_y)`.

If `N==gridsize_x*gridsize_y`, then just do `data[:,2].reshape(gridsize_x,gridsize_y)`.

If the number of rows `N` is not equal to `gridsize_x*gridsize_y`, then you may find a way to reduce it to that number, which may depend on the kind of data, maybe using a mask.